# JQuery ASP.NET show an image clicking on a row

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to show the image in a dialog when I'm clicking on the row but the image is displayed just in case that I clicked on the relevant image.
For example:
When I'm clicking on the first image it's displayed but this doesn't happen when I click at another point of the rowGrid.

HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridVisualizzaEsercizio" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mGridNoAlign" 
                            PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" OnRowDataBound="GridVisualizzaEsercizio_RowDataBound"
                            OnRowCreated="GridVisualizzaEsercizio_RowCreated" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridVisualizzaEsercizio_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            OnRowCommand="GridVisualizzaEsercizio_RowCommand" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#507CD1" >
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkSelect" src="../Images/arrow-right_Smartphone.png" CssClass="img-responsive" runat="server" Text="Visualizza"></asp:ImageButton>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>                                
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Giorno" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="Giorno" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" Visible="true" HeaderText="Giorno" ReadOnly="true" />

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Gruppo" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="Gruppo" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" Visible="true" HeaderText="Gruppo" ReadOnly="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="NomeEsercizio" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="NomeEsercizio" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" Visible="true" HeaderText="Esercizio" ReadOnly="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Serie" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" Visible="true" HeaderText="Serie" ReadOnly="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Ripetizioni" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" Visible="true" HeaderText="Ripetizioni" ReadOnly="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Peso" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" Visible="true" HeaderText="Peso" ReadOnly="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Recupero" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" Visible="true" HeaderText="Recupero" ReadOnly="true" />

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Immagine" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="img-responsive hidden-xs">                                        
                                        <asp:Image ID="img" CssClass="PathImmagine" runat="server" src='<%#Eval("PathImmagine")%>' Width="208px"/>
                                            <%--<img src='<%#Eval("PathImmagine")%>' onclick="DisplayImage(this)" Width="208" />--%>
                                            <%--<button id="btnGif"  runat="server">GIF</button>  --%>

                                        </div>                                                                          
                                    </ItemTemplate>                                   
                                </asp:TemplateField>                                                                                                
                             </Columns>                           
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
                            Giorno:<span id="giorno"></span><br />
                            Gruppo:<span id="gruppo"></span><br />
                            Esercizio:<span id="esercizio"></span><br />
                            Immagine:<span id="pathimmagine"></span>
                        </div>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("[id*=GridVisualizzaEsercizio]").live("click", function () {
                debugger;

            $("#giorno").html($(".Giorno", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
            $("#gruppo").html($(".Gruppo", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
            $("#esercizio").html($(".NomeEsercizio", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
            $("#pathimmagine").html($(".PathImmagine", $(this).closest("tr")).html('src', 'PathImmagine'));

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "Scheda Allenamento",
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What you're describing isn't very clear.  What specifically isn't working?  What's the resulting HTML code that this JavaScript code is using?

Comment: The image is deplayed properly when I clicked on the "Image" but I want to show the image when I'm clicking on every point of the row.

Comment: Then I guess you would change your jQuery selector from identifying the image element to identifying the row element.  But you're not showing your relevant HTML in the question, so that's about as specific as anyone here can get.

Comment: `.live` is deprecated and shouldn't be used for any new jQuery code. `.on` replaced it in jQuery 1.7 (all the way back in 2011!!)